# Let $V$ be vector space over field $K$ and $v_1, ...v_n \in V$ be linearly independent Show $v_1, v_1+v_2, ...v_1+v_2+...v_n$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, systems-of-equations

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$ and let $v_1, ... v_n \in V$ be linearly independent. Show that $v_1$, $v_1 + v_2$, $\ldots$, $v_1 + v_2 + \cdots+ v_n$ are linearly independent.

---

This question here [Suppose $v_1,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_2+v_3,...,\sum_{i=1}^nv_i$ are linear independent. Show that $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ are also linear independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043298/suppose-v-1-v-1v-2-v-1v-2v-3-sum-i-1nv-i-are-linear-independent-sh) seems to do the opposite.

Comment: What you did is nonsensical. To show that vectors $w_1$, $w_2,\ldots,w_n$ are linearly independent, you assume $a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n=0$ and need to show $a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$. You do **not** start with $a_1 w_1=0$, then take that *same* $a_1$ and consider $a_1w_1+a_2w_2=0$, etc. So, no. This is very much not correct, and suggests you are very wobbly on what it means to show a set of vectors is linearly independent.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Uh yeah, in fact. So we would have $a_1v_1 + a_2(v_1 + v_2) + ... a_n(v_1 + v_2 + ... v_n) = 0$.  Expanding everything, we have $v_1(a_1 + ... a_n) + v_2(a_2 + ... a_n) + v_n a_n = 0$. If $a_n \neq 0$ then $v_n = 0$. If we do that $n$ times, assuming all coefficients are non-zero, we get $v_n = ... = v_1 = 0$. So the only solution with non-zero coefficients is the zero vector, which is trivial. So to have non-zero vectors, the coefficients need to be zero. Is that correct ?

Comment: Now you are confusing vectors and scalars. You get $(a_1+\cdots+a_n)v_1 + (a_2+\cdots+a_n)v_2 + \cdots + a_nv_n=0$. Now *use the assumption that $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent. Again, you don't get to just "assume" that $a_n\neq 0$ and "conclude" $v_n=0$ (which is **impossible** if $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent vectors...)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If they are linearly independent, then ($a_1 + ... a_n = 0$), ($a_2 + ... a_n = 0$), ... ($a_n = 0$).  Because if they are linearly independent, then the only solution to $b_1v_1 + ... b_nv_n = 0$ is $b_1 = ... = b_n = 0$. So in our case $b_1 = a_1 + ... a_n, ..., b_n = a_n$. So $b_n = a_n = 0$. We have $a_n + a_{n-1} = 0$, we know $a_n = 0 \implies a_{n-1} = 0$. If we do that for all equations, we get $a_n = a_{n-1} = ... a_1 = 0$. Is this more accurate ?

Comment: The previous one were just wrong. This one is, once you actually put in the correct symbols and write it out carefully, correct. So "more accurate" in the sense of "this one is right,  the others were wrong."

Comment: You should consider coefficients at the other end. Call the new vectors by $w_2,w_2,\ldots ,w_n.$ If $a_1w_1+\ldots +a_nw_n=0,$ then $a_n=0$ as $w_n$ is the only vector where $v_n$ shows up. Then you move to $a_{n-1}$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer my own question, thanks to @ArturoMagidin and @RyszardSzwarc

If they are linearly independent, then ($a_1 + ... a_n = 0$), ($a_2 + ... a_n = 0$), ... ($a_n = 0$).  Because if they are linearly independent, then the only solution to $b_1v_1 + ... b_nv_n = 0$ is $b_1 = ... = b_n = 0$. So in our case $b_1 = a_1 + ... a_n, ..., b_n = a_n$. So $b_n = a_n = 0$. We have $a_n + a_{n-1} = 0$, we know $a_n = 0 \implies a_{n-1} = 0$. If we do that for all equations, we get $a_n = a_{n-1} = ... a_1 = 0$.